# Problems with Zonminder and MySQL after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, mysql, zoneminder

Upgrading to 16.04 is a nightmare... it has broken everything on my server that has been running for 10 years.

I am slowly trying to get my server working again ... as of now I'm dealing with Zoneminder. I had it working fine yesterday but today when I tried to log in it would just go back to the log in screen and I checked the logs and was getting an error stating WAR [Login denied for user "myusername"]. I went into the MySQL database and deleted my password and was able to get in. I went to the options and users and tried to put in a new password and I get an error

```
SQL-ERR 'SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'Password' at row 1', statement was 'update Users set Password = password('********') where Id = ?'
```

If I try to save any changes to a 'source' it will also just throw an error.. for example if I click on the 'source' and bring up the monitors properties (where you can change stuff like buffers and timestamp) and just click save without even changing anything I will get this error:

```
SQL-ERR 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ServerId' at row 1', statement was 'update Monitors set ServerId = '', AnalysisFPS = '', Triggers = '' where Id =?'
```

As of now it will function but without any way of changing any settings or protecting the streams with a password. I think the DB is completely screwed up or MySQL is still screwed up ... I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around a bit and was able to fix this problem ... I used [This Tutorial](https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Ubuntu_Server_16.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.29.0_the_easy_way#Ubuntu_16.04_with_LAMP) to fix the issue. Once I added the things it mentioned and made sure the permissions were correct I was able to change settings without an error.